# What is the meaning of the "t" in the code and what does t(window) mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jquery/javascript by looking at the source code of some websites. I am a bit unsure about the syntax used there:

```
!function(t) {
    "use strict";

        function e() {
        var e = parseInt(t(window).scrollTop()),
            n = 10;
        e > n ? a.addClass("new-class") : (a.removeClass("new-class"), t(".sclass").removeClass("fclass"))
    }
    //...more codes...
}(jQuery),
```

I just don't really get what exactly is the meaning of that t there. Is it "this" or just any event object? and what does t(window) means? I thought it should be something like t.window? Since t is not a function.

Thanks!
Saldtch

Comment: This is minified code, and it's pointless to post it in a question. If you want info on IIFEs, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript

Comment: I think you used a `!` instead of a `(`

Comment: @user3558931: Minifiers will do this for you, as it's one less character than wrapping the function in parentheses to force an expression.

Comment: man you guys answer super super super quick! Let me try to digest!

Answer (score 3):

`t` is a reference to the `jQuery` object within the scope of that function.  Notice how the function is called:

```
!function (t) {
    // "t" is the jQuery object
}(jQuery);
```

The function is defined and then immediately invoked with the parameter `jQuery`.  So when the function is invoked, that parameter being passed is stored in the variable `t`.  You could name it anything, really:

```
!function (foo) {
    // "foo" is the jQuery object
}(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined inline, so it doesn't have a name, and immediatley gets called with param jQuery. "t" is the formal parameter of the inline function, which gets resolved with the concrete parameter "jQuery".

Shortly, variable `t` refers to the `jQuery` object (or whatever jQuery variable holds).

Answer (score 0):

That's equivalent to:

```
function x(t) {
    //code in here
}

x(jQuery);
```

Therefore `t` is a local reference in the function to `jQuery`.

**And,** `t(window)` is equivalent to `jQuery(window)` ...  and by extension `$(window)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think i got this, but what about that t(window)? It doesn't look like a formal syntax to me. Or this is just minified code? (Again doesn't look like something formal to me)

Comment: Whenever you wrap an element in `jQuery( .. )` or `$( .. )` you are able to manipulate the element using `jQuery` methods. See my updated code above. Does that help?

Comment: Yes I got that already thanks! (the above comment was added BEFORE your answer was updated :))

Comment: Great! Glad it's all coming together.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in the function `e()`:

```
console.log(t === jQuery);
```

You will assert that `t` is `jQuery` alias indeed in that function.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above, t equals to the jquery object in this case. t(window) means, wrap the window object with the jquery object, so after wrapping it, i can call jquery methods on it. I'm sure you are already familiar with jquery's $(selector) method, which does the same (fair enough).

So, `$('#product')` should get the DOM element with id *"product"* and wrap it inside a jquery object.

**Example**:

```
var myProduct = document.querySelector('#product');
myProduct.attr('id'); // error, myProduct doesn't have method attr() because it is not a jquery "instance"
$(myProduct).attr(id); // product, we wrapped the item in a jquery object
```

Since jquery is named as **t** in your example, `t(window)` is wrapping the window object in jquery. The window object normally doesn't have a `scrollTop()` method defined on it.

Comment: Yes and now I am not sure why the site programmer didn't just use "$" instead of the "t". That's where I got confused. I am too used to thinking this: jQuery(document).ready(function($){...some codes...} ( jQuery, window ); as the standard.

Comment: Maybe it was just the result of some minification. By the way, you should stick to that form:
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // code here        
        });
    }(jQuery));

Comment: Thanks! Somehow the reference I am learning from always use the form jQuery(document).ready(function($){...some codes...} ( jQuery, window )